# production.ERROR: Illegal string offset 'hash'

Tags: php, laravel

I have a script where the user places a credit via pix through the PAGGUE platform, but when generating the qr code it gives this error:

```
production.ERROR: Illegal string offset 'hash' {"userId":15,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Illegal string offset 'hash' at /var/www/html/app/Http /Controllers/PagesController.php:1220)
```

On line 1220 there is this code:

```php
$payment->secret = $response['hash'];
```

I already tried to ignore the hash, but the qr code is invalid

Comment: Hi, looks like $response not giving the response so can you please check the $response value? if $response is null and you are trying to get then it will give the error.

Comment: Apparenty `$response` is a string, not an array. You'll have to show the rest of the code of that function to figure out why.